# Compiled template reference is undefined when calling dust.loadSource() in browser

Tags: javascript, dust.js

I'm trying to render HTML using compiled templates with dust.js in a browser (not server-side with node.js). If I compile the template in the client-side javascript, it works fine. If I pre-compile the template and include it as a script tag as recommended, the dust.loadSource statement results in the Chrome debugger saying: "Uncaught ReferenceError: nowork is not defined", where "nowork" is the template name. So...

This HTML and script works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>This Works</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dust-full-0.3.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="bingo"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var templateKey = 'works';
        var myView = {"people":[{"name":"Fred"},{"name":"Harry"},{"name":"Linda"},{"name":"Mary"}]};

        dust.loadSource(dust.compile("{#people}<br/>{name}{/people}", templateKey));
        dust.render(templateKey, myView, function(err, out) {
            $('#bingo').html(out);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>This Doesn't Work</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dust-full-0.3.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="nowork.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="bingo"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var templateKey = 'nowork';
        var myView = {"people":[{"name":"Fred"},{"name":"Harry"},{"name":"Linda"},{"name":"Mary"}]};

        dust.loadSource(templateKey);
        dust.render(templateKey, myView, function(err, out) {
            $('#bingo').html(out);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Where the included nowork.js file contains:

```
(function() {
    dust.register("nowork", body_0);

    function body_0(chk, ctx) {
        return chk.section(ctx.get("people"), ctx, {
            "block": body_1
        }, null);
    }
    function body_1(chk, ctx) {
        return chk.write("<br/>").reference(ctx.get("name"), ctx, "h");
    }
    return body_0;
})();
```

Can anyone help?

I just realized, that this may be due to these files not being served on a machine with node.js installed. I'm actually working locally on my desktop machine. Is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need to call `dust.loadSource` when you are serving pre-compiled templates. Internally, `dust.loadSource` just does an `eval` on the string of JavaScript that is returned by `dust.compile`. If you remove the `dust.loadSource` line, your template should render properly.

Node.js isn't necessary for what you are attempting here. As a matter of fact, dust-full isn't necessary, either. You can use dust-core if all you are doing is rendering on the client.

Comment: You are correct. Omitting the loadSource call worked. I knew you only needed dust-core. My inclusion of dust-full was left over from doing the compile step in the page script. Thank you!